# How to fill the space using Linear Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I am using the Linear Layout with 6 buttons in it.
Based on the permissions the Buttons are set visible or invisible.

Button1
Button2
Button3
Button4
Button5
Button6

Based on User Permissions

Button1

Button3
Button4

Button6

My question is: is there a way to make the display as

Button1
Button3
Button4
Button6

Can android xml for layouts manage this, and if yes how?

Comment: Why was this question voted down. If it makes sense to users and other helpers it should not atleast be voted down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve your goal:

**1** - Set your LinearLayout width to match_parent and its orientation to horizontal:

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
```

This will make your buttons lay on a row.

**2** - Set all the buttons weight to 1 and their widths to 0dp:

```
android:layout_weight="1"
android:layout_width="0dp"
```

This will make your buttons fill the space horizontally, in percentage (each one will be given the same width)

**3** - If you programmatically set the visibility to `View.GONE`, the invisible buttons will take **no space**, leaving the other buttons more space to fill (they will automatically grow in size). By setting the visibility to `View.VISIBLE`, again, the visible Button will reclaim its space and the Buttonn widths will be narrowed

Comment: This worked like a charm as I am very new to stackOverflow i cannot vote up without 15 reputation. the 3 point helped me alot. I am still using layout oreintation as Vertical but with height as 0dp. Thanks Frank.

Answer (score 1):

You just set the orientation horizontal in linearlayout

```
android:orientation="horizontal"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is your layout Please check.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="6" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button 1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button 2"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button 3" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button 4" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn5"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button 5"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/6"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button 6" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: though this explanation is same as next answer by Frank with only difference being the View.GONE part of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using [Layout Weight](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html#Weight) from LinearLayout http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html#Weight

But as you are dynamically changing the set ot buttons, you might have to do it programmatically, for that you can only do it using the [LinearLayout.LayoutParams](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html#LinearLayout.LayoutParams(int,%20int,%20float)) like this:

```
   LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                         LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                         LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 0.5f);


   button.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: cannot use this as min API level for my project is 8 whereas Layout.Params requires API Level 11. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: LinearLayout.LayoutParams is since API level 1...maybe the problem is with the LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT...change that with: LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT it should work the same way.

Comment: actually MATCH_PARENT should be available on API Level 8: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html#MATCH_PARENT

Comment: check if you are really importing the correct LayoutParams.

Comment: Can u suggest which one to be imported

Comment: android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams